# How to add bottom spacing to the expanded DisclosureGroup in a Form?

Tags: swiftui

I have a [DisclosureGroup](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/disclosuregroup) in a [Form](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form).

It looks like this

[image]

When the first item of `DisclosureGroup` is expanded it looks like this

[image]

I want to add some spacing when `DisclosureGroup` is open. Like this

[image]

Here is my code snippet

```
NavigationView {
      Form {
        ForEach(serviceGroups, id: \.self) { serviceGroup in
          DisclosureGroup(serviceGroup) {
            ForEach(services, id: \.self) { service in
              VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                Text(service)
                HStack {
                  Text("$400")
                  Text("1 h. 30 min.")
                }.font(.subheadline)
                  .foregroundColor(.secondary)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

P.S. I added that space (on the third screenshot) by wrapping `DisclosureGroup` in a `Section` manually. How can I do this programmatically?

---